# Having Problem while opening command prompt from shared application

Tags: c#

I have a windows application which has been deployed on Shared Server. My Application will invoke a command prompt to do some DB operations. I am facing problems if I run the application from shared location. I am not facing any problems if I run the application with in the deployed server. The problem I have is as follows.

I pass a few arguments to the command prompt when invoking it. I get the following message if I open the application from shared location and it is not executing the arguments whatever I pass.

```
 CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC
 paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory. Microsoft
 Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
```

Command Prompt invocation code as follows:
Typically command arguments would contain `@"CD \&&C:&&CD\&&CD MyFolder &&CD MySubFolder\App.bat"`

```
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd",  command.ToString());
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
```

I am getting the same problem if I run the .bat file directly as well.

Answer (score 4):

The answer stands in your question:

> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. **UNC
>   paths are not supported.** Defaulting to Windows directory. Microsoft
>   Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm

Summary: a unc path is a network path. And your cmd says that those are not supported.

Comment: I trying to run the following command by invoking a command prompt "@"CD \&&C:&&CD\&&CD MyFolder &&CD MySubFolder\App.bat"" App.Bat is on Client Local Machine it is not on server. Thanks, Venkat Malladi

Answer (score 1):

You can try to utilize the pushd/popd commands to have Windows map the UNC path to a temporary drive:

https://github.com/madskristensen/OpenCommandLine/issues/14#issuecomment-73608382

This should work for the .bat approach, not sure if you would have to exec the .bat file instead of cmd, or if you could pipe.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say from the information you have given but do you realise that when you run an application from a shared location, the application runs on the local client machine and not on the server machine.

So if the application you are running is looking for a file that is on the server then it will not be able to find it without a path that is relative to the client machine.

If you are not trying to open a file or anything like that then please give some additional information

Comment: i am not trying open any file which was there on the server.I am trying to open a command prompt to access a file on the local client machine.

Comment: I trying to run the following command  by invoking a command prompt "@"CD \&&C:&&CD\&&CD MyFolder &&CD MySubFolder\App.bat"" 

App.Bat is on Client Local Machine it is not on server.
Thanks,
Venkat Malladi.

Comment: @Venkat Malladi, Your paths need to be like... "C:\MyFolder\MySubFolder\App.bat" ... What are all these "\&&"parts meant to be?

Comment: Hi ,

I resolved the issue by setting working directory to the Process.

Thanks,
Venkat Malladi.